# Fetching C# Logs in Python

Tags: c#, python, logging, python.net

I have built a python library that uses C# code(which is built and stored as a dll), using pythonnet. In that library, I generate logs using the python logger.

**mylibrary.py**

```
logger = logging.getLogger('mylibrary')
logger.info('logging from my library')
```

The root logger is configured from the user code. For example, the handlers for the root logger is set by the user using logger's "addhandler()" method specifying the format, output file etc. Inside my library, I just log (logger.info()...) without configuring anything and the root handler set by the user takes care of writing this to the file.

**usercode.py**

```
root_logger = getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(FileHandler('abc.log'))
root_handler.setFormat(...)
```

The user can control what my library can log by setting the level of the logger used by my library. The line below in usercode.py sets the logging level of my library's logger to critical so that the library can't log anything below it (logger.info() won't get into abc.log).

```
getLogger('mylibrary').setLevel(CRITICAL)
```

The problem comes now. Since I am using C# code in my library,

1. I want to capture the C# logs into abc.log
2. I also want to configure the C# log just like I did for python logs

So the the line

```
getLogger('mylibrary').setLevel(CRITICAL)
```

in usercode.py should now make sure that only the critical logs in both the python as well as C# get into abc.log

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: you need to provide code sample for both python and c# sides, this question does not make sense in the current state

Comment: @denfromufa, is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot log from both Python and C# at the same time to the same file. The reason for this is that Python's logging (and likely the C# logging too) is not equipped for concurrent logging - even if the log file is not 'locked' by one of them, there is a chance of getting different logs mixed together due to multiple writers.

If you do not own the C# dll you're probably out of luck - unless it would allow you to configure the log file/level from a C# program, there is no magic that Python can do to fix it. However, if you control the source and can build a new dll, consider changing the C# class to allow you to pass in a delegate/lambda (assuming this is implemented in PythonNet), which will simply call back into Python's logger function.

Example:

c# code:

```
public class CoolImportedFeature
{
    private readonly Action<string> LogCallback;

    public CoolImportedFeature(string inputA, int inputB, Action<string, string> logCallback)
    {
        LogCallback = logCallback;
        // do other constructor stuff
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // do something
        LogCallback("critical", "An error occurred");
    }
}
```

python code:

```
def log_callback(log_level, message):
    getattr(logger, log_level)(message)
import CoolImportedFeature
feat = CoolImportedFeature("hello", 1, log_callback)
feat.SomeMethod()
```

Something like that - there is no magic translation between Python's log levels and C#'s, so you will need to do some translation there (or the getattr reflection I used above).